# Извлечение данных JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Здравствуйте, подскажите как вывести `infooption` и чтобы можно было вставить переменную `infooption.valinf`

```
var valinf = "Донецк"; 
var t1 = '{ "infooption":  { "Донецк": ["123","456"] } }';
var infores = JSON.parse(t1);
var infooptionsd = infores.infooption;
var infooption = infooptionsd.valinf;
```

При проверке `console.log(infooption);` выдает **undefined**

Comment: Так а где в `json` описании у вас `valinf`?

Comment: И куда вставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы использовать вычисляемое имя свойства воспользуйтесь квадратными скобками

```js
var valinf = "Донецк"; 
var t1 = '{ "infooption":  { "Донецк": ["123","456"] } }';
var infores = JSON.parse(t1);
var infooptionsd = infores.infooption;
var infooption = infooptionsd[valinf]; // <- заменить обращение через точку на обращение через квадратные скобки
console.log(infooption);
```